# What should I do after drywall compound was flushed into my plumbing drain?

Tags: drywall, drain, pipe

I washed bucket of wet drywall compound down my toilet. Will it clog the pipes?

What might be some possible solutions?

Comment: The question above was, “how much?”

Comment: More than a little

Answer (score 7):

Water-based joint compound can still settle and harden to a degree that it causes clogs, though that's somewhat unlikely given the amount of water in a toilet flush. I'd be running water for say half an hour at the best rate you can muster. It might help to fill a utility sink or bathtub (or several), then release that in a gush. Most of the compound will probably wash away and be diluted, preventing downstream issues.

If you have any indication that a blockage has occurred, you'll need to borrow, rent, or buy a suitable plumbing auger and run the pipes to dislodge the hardened material.

Comment: I suspect that some sort of acid might be used to dissolve the hardened compound.  Of course, acid might damage the pipes and kill the "good bugs" in a septic tank, so some care is necessary if acid is used.

Comment: Acid is not needed.  Drywall compound is water soluble. That is why your are getting so many recommendations to continue running water down the drain.

Comment: Acid would be very difficult to apply in a localized manner to such an extent that a thick gob of compound would be removed. I don't consider that worth doing.

Comment: If water dissolves something, generally hot water (not boiling) dissolves it faster.